# Lightning-edit-form submit only after custom code execution

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation-rule, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-recordviewform, page-validation

I am creating LWC which will have both `<lightning-record-edit-form>` and `<lightning-record-view-form>` elements. I am toggling between these elements to edit and display the record.
My code is as below

HTML:

```
<template>
  <template if:false={showFields}>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={ObjectName} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <lightning-button type="submit" label="Update Record"></lightning-button>
      <!--
      Few fields to update with custom styling
      -->
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
  </template>
  <template if:true={showFields}>
    <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={ObjectName} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <lightning-button onclick={toggleViewEdit} label="Edit Record"></lightning-button>
       <!--
       Few fields to display with custom styling
       -->
    </lightning-record-view-form>
  </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import {lightningElement, api} from 'lwc';

export default class myLWC extends lightningElement{
  @api recordId;
  showFields = true;
  
  toggleViewEdit(){
    if(!this.showFields){
      this.showFields = true;
    }else{
      this.showFields = false;
    }
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    this.toggleViewEdit();//This should only execute after successful submit action
  }
}
```

I only want to switch from `edit-form` to `view-form` when all the validation errors are successfully resolved.
I tried reportValidity(), but still not getting what I need it to be.

Comment: Welcome to sfse! You can try removing `toggleViewEdit()` from handle submit and move it to a new function that can be called from `handleSuccess` of edit form

Comment: Thanks Raul,
How to call that function only after submit is successful?

Comment: Similar to onsubmit there is `onsuccess` in [record edit form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below approach

```
    <template>
  <template if:false={showFields}>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={ObjectName} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
      <lightning-button type="submit" label="Update Record"></lightning-button>
      <!--
      
</template>
```

js

```
handleSuccess = (event) => {
    this.toggleViewEdit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sdandamud1 :)
This is working exactly as I want.